# ReferencedColumnNames not mapped to a single property using composite key

Tags: java, dictionary, jpa

Well,
after reading almost every post I decided to post my question because I'm not able to fix it.

- Class A has a Primary Key (4 fields)
- Class B has a Primary Key (2 fields)

  ```
  @Entity
  public class ClassA implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @EmbeddedId
      private ClassAPK id;

      //bi-directional many-to-one association to ClassB
      @OneToMany(mappedBy="classA")
      private Set<ClassB> classB;
  ```

Class B

```
@Entity
public class ClassB implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "ID")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "cod", column = @Column(name = "cod")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "year", column = @Column(name = "year")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "month", column = @Column(name = "month")) })
    @EmbeddedId
    private ClassBPK id;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to ClassA
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName="ID")
             })
    private ClassA classA;


@Embeddable
public class ClassBPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="ID")
    private long id;

    private int day;

    public ClassBPK() {
    }
```

[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: What was the question ?